# error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand - signal connect in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

https://doc.bccnsoft.com/docs/PyQt4/qplaintextedit.html

```
connect(&objQPlainTextEdit, &QPlainTextEdit::cursorPositionChanged,
            this, &MainWindow::extractTextBlock( objQPlainTextEdit.textCursor().block() );
```

`objQPlainTextEdit` is `QPlainTextEdit`'s object as a class member.

```
public:
QPlainTextEdit  objQPlainTextEdit;


public slots:
    void extractTextBlock( const QTextBlock & block )
    {
        std::cout<< "\nswwss:" << block.text().toStdString() << "\n";
    }
```

This error shows in the connect statement : `error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand`

Please point out the fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call `extractTextBlock(objQPlainTextEdit.textCursor().block())` in the slot then you can use a lambda (untested)...

```
connect(&objQPlainTextEdit, &QPlainTextEdit::cursorPositionChanged, this,
        [this]()
          {
            extractTextBlock(objQPlainTextEdit.textCursor().block());
          });
```

The problem with your code as it stands is that the following...

```
extractTextBlock(objQPlainTextEdit.textCursor().block())
```

is actually a call to `extractTextBlock` which returns `void`.  So with...

```
&MainWindow::extractTextBlock(objQPlainTextEdit.textCursor().block())
```

you are actually attempting to take the address of the temporary 'void' returned -- hence the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Is objQPlainTextEdit declared as a pointer or not? If it is declared as a pointer then take the "&" off.

Also the in a connect call you don't pass parameters. Qt will stick the parameters in for you.